# HikariCP connection leak detection in yaml

Tags: java, mysql, spring

What is the property name if we need to set leak detection in yaml file ? I tried this in yaml and both of these doesn't seem to get picked.

datasource: driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver hikari:
maximum-pool-size: 20
leakDetectionThreshold: 60000 # 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Do you use spring?
See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-sql

Example

```
 spring:
    datasource:
        url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useSSL=false'
        username: root
        password: pass
        driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        hikari:
            minIdle: 10
            leakDetectionThreshold: 60000 
            maximumPoolSize: 30
```